# How to transfer file from one ubuntu server to another ubuntu server?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server

I am new to servers and currently I am stuck in a problem. I want to transfer a while from one server to another. I am using ubuntu through a putty. Both the servers have a private key. So can someone help me out with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your steps should be:

1. Copy ssh  key from Windows machine to source Linux machine.
2. Configure Windows Putty client to use ssh key upon connections to source Linux machine.
3. Connect to to source machine.
4. Run scp command to transfer file to destination Linux machine.

Steps detalization:

1. It could be done using WinSCP client. This link will help you:https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/ssh_winscp.htm
2. Your configuration screen could look like:
   [image: Putty ssh key]
3. It's clear.
4. Run

   scp -i ssh_key_file_with_path source_file_name_with_path username@destination_host:destination_folder

**More about scp command** http://www.tecmint.com/scp-commands-examples/

**Example:**
You want to transfer /home/superuser/script.py to 10.62.96.12 server into /var/www folder. You command could look like:

```
scp -i ~/some_ssh_keys/id_rsa /home/superuser/script.py root@10.62.96.12:/var/www
```

P.S. Make sure your user have enough rights to access source file and destination folder.

Comment: but what if I have private key for both of them

Comment: @SusanWilliams updated the answer. Let me know if it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

Putty is windows client. You can use your Windows box and to transfer file/s in two steps: 1. server1 -> your pc and 2. your pc -> server 2.

You can do this with putty ([here is a howto](http://www.it.cornell.edu/services/managed_servers/howto/file_transfer/fileputty.cfm#puttytrans)) or by using WinSCP ([download link](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php))

Answer (score 0):

This is works in ubuntu
 ==>  scp "file" "username"@"IP address or hostname":"Destination"

Or just download WinScp and transfer the file to your local m/c and then to the other server.

Comment: I know how to do that but what i want is to directly transfer the file between servers

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

**Step 1 :**

- Login to the server(from where you want to transfer the file to another server) using putty.

[image]

**Step 2:**

- Once successfully login to the server then this linux command you have to use :

  scp filename (another ubuntu server IP)XX.XXX.XX.XX:/path/

Here,

**filename** = `File name you have to transfer to another server.`
**XX.XXX.XX.XX** = `Ubuntu Server IP on which you transfer the file.`
**path** = `Specify the Path where you want to transfer the file.`

then, you see the message on your terminal :

`Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?` yes

```
Warning: Permanently added '(another ubuntu server IP)XX.XXX.XX.XX' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```